# Scrapy Crawl Spider Only Scrape Certain Number Of Layers

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I want to crawl all the pages of a web using Scrapy CrawlSpider class ([Documentation here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example)).

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'abc.com'
    allowed_domains = ['abc.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.abc.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        ...
```

(1) So, this spider will start from page: www.abc.com which is defined in the start_urls, and it will automatically do the parsing... and then follow every single link in the www.abc.com which follows the rule right? I am wondering is there a way so I could only scrape a certain number of layers..  say only scrape the 1st layer (links directly derived from www.abc.com)?

(2) Since i have defined in the allowed_deomains that only abc.com urls would be scraped. So I don't need to redefine that in the rules? and do something like this:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), allow_domains="www.abc.com", callback='parse_item')
```

(3) If I am using crawlspider, what will happen if I don't define rules in the spider class? it will crawl follow all the pages? or it would not even follow any single one because the rule has not been 'met'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Set [DEPTH_LIMIT](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit) setting:

   > DEPTH_LIMIT¶
   >
   > Default: 0
   >
   > The maximum depth that will be allowed to crawl for any site. If zero,
   >   no limit will be imposed.
2. No, you don't need to add an additional url check. If you don't specify `allow_domains` on the `Rule` level,  it will extract only URLs with `abc.com` domain.
3. If you don't define rules it won't extract any URLs (will work like a `BaseSpider`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi alecxe, thanks a lot for your answer and I don't know if it is appropriate to keep asking questions in this page so I started a new thread with further questions. You are more than welcome to take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903197/scrapy-xpath-all-the-links-on-the-page