# Scrapy XPath all the links on the page

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to collect all the URLs under a domain using Scrapy. I was trying to use the CrawlSpider to start from the homepage and crawl their web. For each page, I want to use Xpath to extract all the hrefs. And store the data in a format like key-value pair.

Key: the current Url
Value: all the links on this page.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'abc.com'
    allowed_domains = ['abc.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.abc.com']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()), )
    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = AbcItem()
        item['key'] = response.url 
        item['value'] = hxs.select('//a/@href').extract()
        return item
```

I define my AbcItem() looks like below:

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

```
class AbcItem(Item):

    # key: url
    # value: list of links existing in the key url
    key = Field()
    value = Field()
    pass
```

And when I run my code like this:

```
nohup scrapy crawl abc.com -o output -t csv &
```

The robot seems like began to crawl and I can see the nohup.out file being populated by all the configurations log but there is no information from my output file..  which is what I am trying to collect, can anyone help me with this? what might be wrong with my robot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have defined a callback for a rule. Here's an example for getting all links from `twitter.com` main page (`follow=False`):

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class MyItem(Item):
    url= Field()


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'twitter.com'
    allowed_domains = ['twitter.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.twitter.com']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=False), )

    def parse_url(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item
```

Then, in the output file, I see:

```
http://status.twitter.com/
https://twitter.com/
http://support.twitter.com/forums/26810/entries/78525
http://support.twitter.com/articles/14226-how-to-find-your-twitter-short-code-or-long-code
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, callback makes it work! you did follow=False in your code so it only scrape the twitter.com right? No crawling in this case..?  I am pretty sure we have a similar RULE right now with the follow flag set to False, but seems like my spider is still crawling... http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

Comment: Sure, it's scraping just index page `twitter.com`, but if I set `follow=True` it will follow the links and scrape links there too.

Comment: And how can I write a filter to search for any html element that contains id/class/data-type/value of name or what so ever =

Comment: For python3, use `from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor` instead of `SgmlLinkExtractor`

Comment: Also, try `from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule`instead of `from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule`

Comment: Looks like twitter doesn't want to be crawled: `2019-05-12 15:18:34 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET http://www.twitter.com>
`

Answer (score -1):

if you dont set the callback function explicitly, scrapy will use the method `parse` to process crawled pages. so, you should add parse_item as the callback, or change it's name to parse.